# ngx-markdown cutting first 10 characters after a line break

Tags: angular, markdown

In an Angular 5 application, I'm using ngx-markdown to parse valid markdown text.
After a line break, it always cuts the first 10 characters of the next line.

For example, take

```
***Example.*** This should be *valid markdown* text.  
Note the two trailing spaces at the end of the last line.  
And after the previous line.
```

in `<markdown>` (or `<markdown ngPreserveWhitespaces>` for that matter) this would come out as below (without the extra line breaks between every line):

> ***Example.*** This should be *valid markdown* text.
>
> wo trailing spaces at the end of the last line.
>
> the previous line.

Of course an obvious workaround would be adding any 10 characters to the start of every new line but that's a Band-Aid fix I wouldn't like having to resort to.
Oddly, `<br>` doesn't create a new line but *does* cut 11 characters from whatever comes after it. It's also not actually removed from the text, so replacing the trailing white spaces with `<br>` would result in this:

> ***Example.*** This should be *valid markdown* text.`<br>` wo trailing spaces at the end of the last line.`<br>` the previous line.

I've tried using three trailing spaces as well, with the same result. Adding an extra line break also does nothing, other than creating an additional, unnecessary line for every line break.
I must be doing something wrong but I'm not seeing it myself, any ideas?

EDIT: I miscounted, it's actually 10 characters, not 11.
EDIT2: Okay it doesn't seem to consistently cut 10 characters, it varies slightly. I have no idea what's causing this but it unfortunately cuts out the band-aid fix I suggested earlier.